# Randomly select 10% of training set for cross validation in caret R

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a model like the following:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

library(caret)
set.seed(998)

my_data <- Sonar

fitControl <-
  trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 10,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = T,
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )


model <- train(
  Class ~ .,
  data = my_data,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = fitControl,
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

However, using 10 fold cross validation, it keeps the folds that are chosen constant based on the rows in which the samples appear in the training data.

How can I make it randomly select 10% of the training data as a resample for cross validation? I believe this is referred to as Monte Carlo cross validation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
fitControl <-
  trainControl(
  method = "LGOCV",
  p = 10,
  classProbs = T,
  savePredictions = T,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
)
```

Monte carlo cross validation is also known as leave-group out cross-validation (LGOCV)

"p" is the training percentage

more info https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51416/k-fold-vs-monte-carlo-cross-validation

and http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/11/27/vpuig01pqbklmi72b8lcl3ij5hj2qm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using `repeatedcv` along with the argument `repeats=` will resample the cross validation.

```
fitControl <-
  trainControl(
    method = "repeatedcv",
    number = 10,
    repeats = 5,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = T,
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )
```

[Source](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html)